# Region Text is not passing along with form

Tags: magento2.4, uicomponent, knockoutjs, knockout, country-regions

I have created magento admin form using `Uicomponent` with `country` and `state` everything working fine except region value is not passing along with form.This happens only when there is select box appended for choose state option.

In DB two field is there `region` and `region_id` when drop down value selected it should save drop down value in region field and when there is no state available for any country it will show textbox on form and whatever value passed it will save and it is actually saved.But when drop down selected int id of selected stated is saved in `region_id` but not actual text updated in `region` db column.

Here is my code from `Uicomponent` file.

```
 <field name="country_id" sortOrder="280">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="options" xsi:type="object">Magento\Directory\Model\Config\Source\Country</item>
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Country</item>
                <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">select</item>
                <item name="source" xsi:type="string">testMod</item>
                <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/form/element/country</item>
                <item name="validation" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="required-entry" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                </item>
            </item>
        </argument>
    </field>
    <field name="region">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">State/Region</item>
                <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">input</item>
                <item name="source" xsi:type="string">testMod</item>
                <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">281</item>
                <item name="visible" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
    </field>
    <field name="region_id">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="options" xsi:type="object">Magento\Directory\Model\ResourceModel\Region\Collection</item>
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">State/Region</item>
                <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">select</item>
                <item name="source" xsi:type="string">testMod</item>
                <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">300</item>
                <item name="customEntry" xsi:type="string">region</item>
                <item name="validation" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="required-entry" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                </item>
                <item name="filterBy" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="target" xsi:type="string">${ $.provider }:${ $.parentScope }.country_id</item>
                    <item name="field" xsi:type="string">country_id</item>
                </item>
            </item>
        </argument>
    </field>
```